# 301 redirect whole site to the homepage of another?

Tags: redirects

I would like to redirect my whole site to the homepage of another site. I know I could do this in JavaScript but I prefer to have the 301 Redirect for SEO reasons. How could I do this while maintaining the 301 redirect?

At the moment I changed the .htaccess file with:

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newdomain.com/
```

but when someone types `olddomain.com/something/` instead of going into the homepage of the new site, they go to `newdomain.com/something/`.

How can I fix this while maintaining the 301 redirect for SEO reasons?

Comment: Redirecting en masse to a single page may not have the SEO benefit you're expecting.

Answer (score 1):

This will do the trick in .htaccess provided you have mod_rewrite module installed:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example2.com/? [R=301,L]
```

Just replace example with your domain and example2.com with the new domain to redirect to.